# Assignment and retrieval using subscript and equals operator overloads

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variable-assignment, subscription

I've been having a hell of a time trying to solve this. What I am trying to do is use operator overloading so that my objects behave more like a multi dimensional array. I've found solutions to several of the smaller problems involved in making this happen but whenever I try to put it all together there is one issue or another, either lvalue assignment error or invalid initialization from rvalue or just straight up seg fault. I would appreciate any advice TY.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string> 

class Matrix {
  std::string **m;
 public:
  Matrix(int x, int y) {
    m = new std::string*[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
      m[x] = new std::string[y];
  }
  class Proxy {
    std::string *mm;
    int lastIndex = 0;
  public:
    Proxy(std::string *s) : mm(s) {}
      std::string &operator[](int index) {
      lastIndex = index;
      return mm[index];
    }
    std::string &operator=(std::string s) {
      mm[lastIndex] = s;
      return mm[lastIndex];
    }
  };
  Proxy operator[](int index) {
    return Proxy(m[index]);
  }
};

int main()
{
  Matrix *m = new Matrix(5, 5);
  m[2][2] = std::string("It Works");
  std::cout << m[2][2] << std::endl;
  return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()`, `m` is a *pointer* to a `Matrix` object, so you need to dereference the pointer in order to access the `Matrix` object so you can invoke your `Matrix::operator[]` on it, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
  Matrix *m = new Matrix(5, 5);
  (*m)[2][2] = "It Works";
  std::cout << (*m)[2][2] << std::endl;
  delete m;
  return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/CDGd98)

Otherwise, the pointer is not really needed in your example to begin with, eg:

```cpp
int main()
{
  Matrix m(5, 5);
  m[2][2] = "It Works";
  std::cout << m[2][2] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/hqD8C1)

Either way, your `Proxy` does not need to implement `operator=` at all, eg:

```cpp
class Proxy {
  std::string *mm;
public:
  Proxy(std::string *s) : mm(s) {}

  std::string& operator[](int index) {
    return mm[index];
  }
};
```

A statement like `m[2][2] = "...";` will not invoke your `Proxy::operator=`, it will invoke only `Proxy::operator[]`. A statement like `m[2] = "...";` would be needed to invoke `Proxy::operator=`, which doesn't make sense to do in a multi-dimensional scenario.

---

Also, your `Matrix` constructor has a bug - writing to `m[x]` is going out of bounds of the `m[]` array, so the array is not actually filled at all, and you are corrupting surrounding memory, *and* leaking memory.  You need to write to `m[i]` instead:

```cpp
//m[x] = new std::string[y];
m[i] = new std::string[y];
```

After fixing that, `Matrix` is *still* leaking memory, as it does not implement a destructor to free the `std::string`s.  You must `delete[]` anything you `new[]` (same with `delete` and `new`).

And then, you should finish off implementing support for the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), by implementing a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator (your example code does not need them, but production code should always have them), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <utility>

class Matrix {
    std::string **m;
    int m_x, m_y;
public:
    Matrix(int x = 0, int y = 0) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {
        m = new std::string*[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
            m[i] = new std::string[y];
    }

    Matrix(const Matrix &src) : m_x(src.m_x), m_y(src.m_y) {
        m = new std::string*[m_x];
        for (int i = 0; i < m_x; ++i) {
            m[i] = new std::string[m_y];
            for (int j = 0; j < m_y; ++j) {
                m[i][j] = src.m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_x; ++i)
            delete[] m[i];
        delete[] m;
    }

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix &rhs) {
        if (&rhs != this) {
            Matrix temp(rhs);
            std::swap(m, temp.m);
            std::swap(m_x, temp.m_x);
            std::swap(m_y, temp.m_y);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
    class Proxy {
        std::string *mm;
    public:
        Proxy(std::string *s) : mm(s) {}

        std::string& operator[](int index) {
            return mm[index];
        }
    };

    Proxy operator[](int index) {
        return Proxy(m[index]);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Matrix m(5, 5);
 
    m[2][2] = "It Works";
    std::cout << m[2][2] << std::endl;
 
    Matrix m2(m);
    std::cout << m2[2][2] << std::endl;
 
    Matrix m3;
    m3 = m2;
    std::cout << m3[2][2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/HkBaF7)

However, rather than using `new[]` manually, consider using `std::vector` instead (which you are already aware of, since you have `#include <vector>` in your code). This way, the Rule of 3/5/0 can be handled entirely by the compiler for you. `std::vector` and `std::string` are both fully compliant with the Rule, and so any compiler-generated destructor, copy constructor, and copy-assignment operator in `Matrix` will suffice, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string> 

class Matrix {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> m;
public:
    Matrix(int x = 0, int y = 0) {
        m.resize(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
            m[i].resize(y);
    }

    class Proxy {
        std::vector<std::string> &mm;
    public:
        Proxy(std::vector<std::string> &s) : mm(s) {}

        std::string& operator[](int index) {
            return mm[index];
        }
    };

    Proxy operator[](int index) {
        return Proxy(m[index]);
    }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/KU1cDx)

Comment: So to have `m[2][2] = ". . ."` assignment work i would have to have a second proxy class? When I tried that I couldn't figure out how to make `m[2][2]` return the string itself

Comment: @JimSomers No, the 1 `Proxy` will suffice. The 1st `[2]` is called on the `Matrix` object to invoke `Matrix::operator[]` to return a `Proxy` object. Then the 2nd `[2]` is called on the `Proxy` object to invoke `Proxy::operator[]` to return a `std::string&` reference. The compiler will then invoke `std::string::operator=` to assign the new value to the target `std::string` directly.

Comment: idk I tried all those changes and its still seg faulting :-/ Maybe I will try running it through GDB

Comment: @JimSomers I have updated my answer with working demos, as well as explain some other issues your example code has.