# Matrix of pointers using subscription

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, subscript

So a few days ago I asked and received a very good answer in this thread. [Assignment and retrieval using subscript and equals operator overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69981511/assignment-and-retrieval-using-subscript-and-equals-operator-overloads/)
Unfortunately my mistake but it was a little to far from my end use scenario, I'm trying to store pointers to the `cchar_t` class in `nucrsesw/ncurses.h` This is what I have currently

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>
#include <ncursesw/panel.h>

class Matrix {
  std::vector<std::vector<cchar_t*>> m;
public:
  Matrix(int x = 0, int y = 0) {
    m.resize(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
      m[i].resize(y);
  }
  class Proxy {
    std::vector<cchar_t*> &mm;
  public:
    Proxy(std::vector<cchar_t*> &c) : mm(c) {}
    cchar_t& operator[](int index) {
      return *mm[index];
    }
  };
  Proxy operator[](int index) {
    return Proxy(m[index]);
  }
};

int main() {
  wchar_t wR = u'W';
  cchar_t *w;
  setcchar(w, &wR, 0, COLOR_PAIR(0), NULL);

  Matrix m(1, 1);
  m[0][0] = *w;
  std::cout << typeid(m[1][1]).name() << std::endl;
}
```

I keep getting invalid initialization of reference type in the second subscript overload function. It may be obvious but CPP is not my primary language. Does anyone know how this can be adapted to store pointers? Thanks in advance.

Note the code is edited to show exactly what happens when it seg faults on me.

Comment: `mm[index];` returns a pointer but the return type is `cchar_t&`.

Comment: Why do you use `Proxy` if you are using `std::vector<std::vector<cchar_t*>>`?

Comment: Put it another way - you're _already_ storing pointers to `cchar_t`. So what do you need that `vector` doesn't already do for you?

Comment: @quimby yes i've seen the difference with trying to store return a pointer when the function returns a reference but i am trying to use this function as an lvalue in an equals assignment

Comment: @MarekR because nested classes seem to be the only way to implement nested operator overloads im trying to make a matrix class that operates more like a matrix array meaning a[1][1] = val for assignment and a[1][1] for retreval, i've made it happen as shown in that first link but when i try to adapt it to store pointers it seems to be a big problem for the compiler

Comment: @useless as the code is shown i am storing pointers yes, point is that it wont compile, changing 'mm[index]' to '*mm[index]' will allow it to compile but then it seg faults. try to compile it yourself i'm not writing this for my own amusement.

Comment: @JimSomers you missed the point. You can just return `std::vector<cchar_t*>&` and it will just work. Proxy is handy if you what to have flat vector and return just slice of it.

Comment: @JimSomers Of course you get segfault, `w` is uninitialized pointer. Just use `cchar_t w;`, there is no need for an extra pointer.

Comment: @quimbly deleted all the pointer references on `w` and still it seg faults, also cchar_t in ncurses is always passed via pointer, I would love if i could pass it by value but thats just not how the library works

Comment: @MarekR could you please show an example?

Answer (score 0):

`mm` is a reference to an `std::vector` which holds objects of type `cchar_t*` (pointers to `cchar_t` objects). The subscript operator of `std::vector` returns a reference to the object at the appropriate index. In your case, that would be *a reference to a pointer to `cchar_t`*.
To fix your problem, you can dereference the obtained pointer in the `return` statement: simply change it to `return *mm[index];`.

Comment: I tried that it compiles but then seg faults :-(

Comment: @JimSomers Then create a [mcve] please. The pointer points to a valid, allocated memory, right?

Comment: @quimby ive edited to show exactly the code that is seg faulting on me